# How to change the colour of a png image in any adobe software

Tags: images, colors, png, adobe-illustrator

I have a logo that is a process color and I need to change it to a pantone colour. The only way I could change the colour was if I live traced it but I lost some detail. So I was wondering if there is another way I can do this in any of the adobe software programs without losing any of the quality.

Comment: Without seeing the image it's a guessing game for which of the many ways to accomplish this would be the best, so I'm flagging to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It's a raster image. You can lasso, feather, whatever... but you aren't going to have the same quality as you would have with a vector image.

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Illustrator, do the following:

- Go to the `Edit` menu, select `Edit colors` and then `Recolor Artwork`
- Select the target palette in the `Limit the color library` (a color patch icon, in my case at the lower right side of the window) and click `OK`. This results in the target colors, compliant with the chosen colorbook, are shown in the `Swatches` window.
- Select each object you want to recolor and just click the right swatch color. Adjust the tint as necessary.

Another (even quicker way) to do it:

- Select all objects
- Go to the `Edit` menu, select `Edit colors` and then `Recolor with preset` and select the number of base colors you want to use.
- Select the target color library and click `OK` twice.

Answer (score 0):

If your logo is *just one color* (you did say "*a* process color") then you can do it like this:

1. Open it in Photoshop, note the DPI/pixels per inch resolution (Image menu>Image Size...) for later
2. Change color mode to grayscale (Image>Mode>Grayscale), save
3. Open in Illustrator
4. Change the fill color to the Pantone color you want to recolorize it
5. Export back out to PNG. When exporting from Illustrator make sure to set the resolution to the exact same dpi as your original PNG.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i was searching answer for the same question and was hit and trying.

1. Select the png image in illustrator
2. Image Trace
3. Expand
   It will now change into vector and you can see the anchor points.
4. select magic wand tool.
5. select the image you want to change the color.
6. change the color using fill in appearances.
7. select magic wand again.
8. delete the background of image.